# jquery remove selected table's row's background color

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

How do you remove the background color of a selected row, with the help of jquery?

lets assume user selects the row with the id=3, I need to remove the background color.

```
<table class='css_table' style='width: 100%'>
<tr>
    <th style='width: 20%'>Kimden</th>
    <th style='width: 25%'>Konu</th>
    <th style='width: 25%'>Mesaj</th>
    <th style='width: 10%'>Okundu</th>
    <th style='width: 20%'>Tarih</th>
</tr>
<tr id='3' class='selected_row' style='cursor: pointer; background-color: #E0EEEE'>
    <td><span class='row_name'>Prof. Dr.altay tinar</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_subject'>asda da dasd asdasda</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_body'>asda da dasd asdasda</span></td>
    <td><span>0</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_time'>4/15/2013 3:40:40 AM</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id='5' class='selected_row' style='cursor: pointer;'>
    <td><span class='row_name'>Ped.Arifx Yilmazx</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_subject'>undefined asd asdsa </span></td>
    <td><span class='row_body'>qdqw dqw d asda sd </span></td>
    <td><span>1</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_time'>4/15/2013 3:42:36 AM</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

### #HTML

```
<table class="css_table" border="1px">
<tr class='css-row'>
    <th style='width: 20%'>Kimden</th>
    <th style='width: 25%'>Konu</th>
    <th style='width: 25%'>Mesaj</th>
    <th style='width: 10%'>Okundu</th>
    <th style='width: 20%'>Tarih</th>
</tr>
<tr id='3' class='css-row'>
    <td><span>Prof. Dr.altay tinar</span></td>
    <td><span>asda da dasd asdasda</span></td>
    <td><span>asda da dasd asdasda</span></td>
    <td><span>0</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_time'>4/15/2013 3:40:40 AM</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id='5' class='css-row' >
    <td><span class='row_name'>Ped.Arifx Yilmazx</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_subject'>undefined asd asdsa </span></td>
    <td><span class='row_body'>qdqw dqw d asda sd </span></td>
    <td><span>1</span></td>
    <td><span class='row_time'>4/15/2013 3:42:36 AM</span></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

### #CSS Style

```
.css-table
{
   width:100%;
}
.css-row
{
    cursor: pointer; 
    background-color: #E0EEEE;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.css-selectedrow
{
    color:blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight:normal;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

### #Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").click(function(){
      $("table tr").addClass("css-row");
      $(this).removeClass("css-row");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery's `css` function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to remove the background color value:

```
var selectedId = 3;
$("#" + selectedId).css("background-color", "");
```

Comment: @nauphal What do you mean? Isn't this what OP is looking for?http://jsfiddle.net/SRH5L/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to be more specific:

```
$(".css_table tr[id='3']").css("background-color", "");
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbRWL/)

Answer (score 0):

try like below, It will help you...

The below function removes the Background of table row on which the user clicks..

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/139/

**JQuery :**

```
$(".css_table tr").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*You Can Try This Code*

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".selected_row").css("background-color", "");
   });
```